# 401 Unauthorized error and i have no idea what i'm doing wrong

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm new to coding because i wanted to make a bot for my discord server. I've been working on it for about a week straight and i was working on a sort of embed chain that would appear with a bunch of different commands. After i was finished, i had gotten the 401 unauthorized command. ive been scowering the internet for answers and i cannot find one to help me. I really have no idea what im doing wrong. I a very long line of code (for all commands in total) and i can only understand that the error appears for wrong tokens? please help. thank you!

Comment: Please put in your full traceback and any code that raises the exception.

Comment: You get HTTP 401 response when you need to authenticate (your request has not been authenticated, because authentication has not yet been provided; or it has and was incorrect).

Comment: You might have gotten a 401 for a trying to do an operation that you don't have permission to